# Import wordpress mysql database to unknown server / domain

Tags: migration, bulk-import

I would like to know if it's possible to import a full database of a wordpress installation (a localhost/production site for example) to another server/domain in automatic way.

I have being doing some research and it suppoused to be some kind of plugin to automatically detect current domain / path etc, and make an automatic replacement in db in the moment to impor the sql file. Detecting automatically the string that it has to be changed and importing th content...

I know Wp Migrate plugin, but with this, you have to know the destination and make the replacement to for the new strings of the new server (path/domain).

I dont know if I explain enough...

Comment: If you don't know where you're moving the wordpress installation to, why do you want to migrate it? Give us a little more detail, please?

Comment: I would like to provide an "universal" .sql file in order to a third party be able to dump the data in the db of a his new installation (whatever domain/path). I will not be the person who made this db dump. I know Worpress has its own way to import data by .xml but this not cover the whole database data, and I would like that.

Comment: So @barrycarter as far as I know, this should be able to be made knowing the path/domain of the new server.., this "variables" maybe could be retrieved by some script and be replaced automatically before importing, maybe some kind of plugin. I really dont know why there is not a plugin doing this in this automativ way. I think is doable but I dont how, my knowledge of programming and php is very basic

Comment: I want to deliver a theme with this kind of import data (whole sql file of WP) so a normal user could dump the whole sql without asking to me for the migration. Thank you ver much for whatever clue you could give me to focus the solution. For me is not enough a .xml file made exporting in the standar way from within WP admin area

Comment: Suggestion: pretend the new domain is example.com (or something) and include scripts that update example.com to the users actual installation?

Comment: yes..., in old times when I did migrations I just use Find/replace in Notepad++, now I use WP Migrate DB plugin, but with this plugin you also need to specify the new domain and path of the destination folder before export it. And as I described the scenario is whatever path / domain with an already exported db (sql).

Comment: Right. I'm saying just make up a domain name and a path and then include customer-specific scripts that rewrite the domain and name to the correct values for that customer.

Comment: I'm using Custom Post Type plugin and Advanced Custom Fields plugin..., and really this export standar way of export data of wp in a xml file is not usefull in this case.

Comment: yes this is the idea, the wonderfull way would be that this process run automatically (retrieveing this data from the current server when is going to be imported the file), or in a semiautomatic way (the user has to specify the new domain before importing)

Comment: and should be doable from admin area...

Comment: I think (if possible permission-wise) you might need to roll your own script for this. I'm looking at a similar problem, did you solve it? If, how?